# Scss - element depth recursive styles

Tags: html, css, sass

Is there a way to make *Scss* check the element depth, and apply recursively added `margin` to that element?

So say I've got this:

```
<span>
  <span>
    <span>
```

Then I would like to have this, but without me typing the resursion:

```
span {
  margin:10px;

  span {
    margin:20px;

     span {
       margin:30px;
```

I don't know the element depth and need this a lot, that's why I don't want to type this by hand. I don't know if I need a depth of 3, or a depth of up to 100.

Comment: Why you can just use `span > span { margin: 10px }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the direct ancestor operator `>`:

```
span > span {
    margin: 10px;
}
```